# test value contain in array on another array

Tags: arrays, bash, function, shell

**Situation**: I have 2 lists.

1. > **list_all_process.ini**
   >    Listing all of my bash scripts
2. > **exclude_proccess.ini**
   >   listing all of my "excluding" bash scripts

---

These contain

> **list_all_process.ini**

```
script-1.0.sh
script-2.0.sh
script-3.0.sh
script-4.0.sh
```

-

> **exclude_proccess.ini**

```
script-3.0.sh
```

---

**What I would like to have:**

If the value doesn't correspond to the exclude proccess -> execute the script. If match -> nothing

My code:

```
except_proccess(){
    readarray a -t < ${INC}/full_proccess_list.ini
    readarray b -t < ${INC}/exclude_list.ini

    for ACCEPT in ${a[@]} ; do
        for DENNY in ${b[@]} ; do
        if [[ $ACCEPT == $DENNY ]]; then
            continue;
        else
            bash ${INC}/${ACCEPT}
        fi  
        done
    done
```

**My problem:**

False positive and ID contain in exclude_list is launched ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering why you do it in such a complicated way. Try this:

```
for p in $(cat list_all_process.ini) ; do
    grep -q "$p" exclude_proccess.ini || echo "execute $p"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch ! Sorry for the complicated way .. It's my first script and I was PHP developper before ... So my brain is in washmachine right now haha.. Thank you ! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept my solution, if your reputation level allows to do so.